# How to store non english unicode characters using dynamic query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to save non-english unicode characters into a table in SQL Server.

```
declare @cSql varchar(200)
set @cSql = ''

declare @cCode varchar(10)
set @cCode = '001'

declare @cKName Nvarchar(200)
set @cKName = N'ಒಂದು'

Insert into DepMast (omCode, omKName)
Values(@cCode, @cKName)
```

On executing the above code, the unicode characters are saved as required.

But, if I use dynamic query, `'?????'` is stored.

```
set @cSql = 'Insert into DepMast (omCode, omKName)
             Values(''' + @cCode + ''',''' + @cKName + ''')'

exec(@cSql)
```

Any ideas on storing unicode characters using dynamic query?

Comment: What is your database collation?

Comment: It is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two reasons for this behaviour - firstly, you have declared `@cSql` as `varchar` datatype and `@cKName` as `nvarchar` datatype. Secondly, you are not prefixing the value with `N` when inserting. This should fix the issue

```
declare @cSql nvarchar(200) --changed datatype to nvarchar
set @cSql=''
declare @cCode varchar(10)
set @cCode='001'
declare @cKName nvarchar(200)
set @cKName=N'ಒಂದು' 
set @cSql='Insert into DepMast (omCode,omKName)
Values('''+@cCode+''',N'''+@cKName+''')' -- added the "N" prefix
exec(@cSql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert Into Select Statement in dynamic query.You need to store your Unicode characters in some reference table with key value.